# Comparing O((logn)!) and O(2^n)

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I am having a hard time comparing these two functions,

(logn)!

and

2^n

Any good mathematical proof?

Comment: look for big-O complexity chart that you will have a better idea about those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare `O((logn)!)` and `O(2^n)` since [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) represents a set. O(g(n)) is the set of of all function f such that f does not grows faster than g, formally is the same is saying that there exists `C` and `n0` such that we have `|f(n)| <= C|g(n)|` for every `n >= n0`. The expression `f(n) = O(g(n))`  is a shorthand for saying that `f(n)` is in the set `O(g(n))`. what we can do is check if `2^n=O((logn)!)` or `(log n)!=O(2^n)` (note that it could be that both are not true). Luckily, if we use the [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) we get that

```
log((logn)!) = (logn)*(log (logn)) - logn + O(log(log n)) = O(n*(log 2))
```

since `n * cost` grows faster than `(logn)*(log (logn))` and `(logn)*(log (logn))` is the leading term in `(logn)*(log (logn)) - logn + O(log(log n))`. So we get that `log((logn)!) = O(log(2^n))` which is same as saying that `(log n)! = O(2^n)`

Answer (score 1):

One can easily show that for sufficiently large `n` it holds that:

```
 log(n)! <= log(n)^{log(n)} <= n^{log(n)} = 2^{log^2(n)}
```

We can now only consider exponents of `2` in the `2^n` and the expression above - `n` and `log^2(n)` respectively (we can do that since we consider only sufficiently large `n` and `2^x` is strictly rising for positive x). It is sufficient to show that the limit below diverges to prove that `log(n)!` is, in fact, `o(2^n)`:

```
lim[n -> inf] (n)/(log^2(n))
```

Now we apply L'Hospital rule:

```
= lim [n -> inf] `n/(2log(n))`
```

And again:

```
= lim [n -> inf] `n/(2)`
```

Which diverges to infinity.